# Where do I store screenshots for 'fastlane supply' command?

Tags: android, fastlane

I have an android app for which I wrote tests to take screenshots (note: I do not use the screengrab of fastlane). I then extract the files from the phone into a temp folder via adb. Now I want to upload those via a fastlane supply command (and nothing else should be uploaded). The task executes successfully but I can't see my screenshots when I check the Google Play Console, so I suspect that my directory structure is wrong.

I've tried various things but by comparing it to a screenshots of their setup [doc](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/setup/)  I assume it has to be something like `fastlane/metadata/en-US/screenshots`

Or are there any requirements for the file names? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output you are getting when running `supply`? Please post the complete output you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the required structure [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/)

So it's `fastlane/metadata/android/en-US/images/phoneScreenshots`.

Answer (score 1):

- The easiest way to get the proper directory structure is to run `fastlane supply init` as described [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/#images-and-screenshots).
- If you want to have these metadata (which includes the screenshots) somewhere else, you can use the `metadata_path` parameter to change that.
- And if you want to limit the upload to just screenshots, use the several `skip_upload_` parameters that are available to turn off things.

Comment: That command only gave me directories fastlane/metadata/android. No Locales or images folder. However, I found the documentation in which they talk about the directory structure. I reproduced it an stored my screenshots accordingly, so now it works.

Comment: You are right, that should be documented better. I created https://github.com/fastlane/docs/issues/852